# Problem with triple integral $\iiint_T 2z \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate triple integral

$$\iiint_T 2z \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z$$

where $$T=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3}:2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<z<x+2\}$$

I'm not sure how to graph this or evaluate this triple integral.

Comment: What about cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: It could be $(x+2)^4/8$?

Comment: Try to make the change of variables $x = r\cos(\theta)$, $y = r\sin(\theta)$ and $z = z$.

Comment: The Answer can not contain $x$ , @Richy65 , it must be a real number.

Comment: Done but how I choose $\theta$ and $r$?

Comment: [[A]] Where was the Question given ? [[B]] It **seems** that the Answer is "unbounded" [[C]] Due to $\sqrt$ , $z$ is Positive [[D]] Letting $y=0$ , we see that $z$ is between $x$ & $x+2$ , where $x$ is "unbounded" , hence $z$ is "unbounded" too. [[E]] Then Integrating $2z$ over that "unbounded" volume **may** give "unbounded" Answer !

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are asked to calculate $$\iiint_{V}h(x,y,z)\,dxdydz$$ over a region $V$ bounded by two surfaces i.e. region given by $f(x,y)<z<g(x,y)$, then what you do is

$$\iint_{S}\int_{g(x,y)}^{f(x,y)}h(x,y,z)\,dx\,dydz$$ where $S$ is the region in the $xy$-plane bounded by the curve $f(x,y)-g(x,y)=0$

So, in your case, you are asked to find the integral over the region trapped between the cone $z=2\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ and the plane $z=x+2$. So, find out the curve of intersection which is just $2\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}=x+2$, i.e. the ellipse, $\dfrac{(x-\frac{1}{3})^{2}}{\frac{13}{9}}+\dfrac{y^{2}}{\frac{13}{12}}=1$.

So, now you use the above result.

You'll get,

$$\iint_{S}\frac{13}{3}-3(x-\frac{1}{3})^{2}-4y^{2}\,dxdy$$

Now you can make a variable change to $u=\dfrac{x-\frac{1}{3}}{\sqrt{13/9}}$ and $v=\frac{y}{\sqrt{13/12}}$ to contract this ellipse into the unit disk

Compute the Jacobian $\bigg|\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}\bigg|=\frac{6\sqrt{3}}{13}$ and then use the usual polar coordinates to integrate over the unit disk.

i.e. $$\iint_{S}\frac{13}{3}\bigg(1-\dfrac{(x-\frac{1}{3})^{2}}{\frac{13}{9}}-\dfrac{y^{2}}{\frac{13}{12}}\bigg)\,dxdy$$

$$=\iint_{D}\frac{13}{3}\cdot\frac{13}{6\sqrt{3}}\bigg(1-u^{2}-v^{2}\bigg)\,du\,dv$$ where $D$ is the unit disk.

Now use polar coordinates to get

$$\frac{169}{18\sqrt{3}}\cdot 2\pi\cdot\int_{0}^{1}(1-r^{2})r\,dr=\frac{169\pi}{36\sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.